Split a string with multiple required delimiters
I have the following string
Text1:/nText/nText2:/nText/nText/nText3:/nText

I'm trying to split it into a dictionary where any line with a ":" is key and anything without that is in value.
IE..
{"Text1":"Text","Text2":"Text Text","Text3":"Text"}

I thought maybe I could split every /n into a dictionary with enumerate but that didn't work in a way that I could match k:v (in the example above it became offset.
This is specifically what I had tried:
infodict = {k+1: v for k, v in enumerate(infostr.split(":"))}

In my head this is like the opposite of splitting on multiple delimiters, there are two required delimiters /n and : and both must be present for the split().
Downstream this data gets added into a larger dataframe, so if there is a different data structure that is more pythonic I don't need to put this into a dictionary in particular.

Do you mean to write \n rather than /n?

What's the question exactly? It seems like part of the problem is that : is not a delimiter here, but I don't understand why you think it is. Check out [ask], which has tips like how to write a good title.

Just take it in steps.
Break up the string:
text = 'Text1:/nText/nText2:/nText/nText/nText3:/nText'
parts = text.split('/n')  # assuming `/n` was not a typo

The parts ending in : will be a new key, anything else gets added together as the value of the current key:
current_key = None
d = {}
for p in parts:
    if p[-1] == ':':
        current_key = p[:-1]
        d[current_key] = ''
    else:
        if current_key is None:
            raise Exception('The first part of text should be a key!')
        # add the first part, or any following part with a space before it
        d[current_key] += p if not d[current_key] else f' {p}'

That gets you what you're asking for:
print(d)

Output:
{'Text1': 'Text', 'Text2': 'Text Text', 'Text3': 'Text'}

There are shorter solutions, but perhaps not as readable. You could also take the above and spell it out a bit more, but I figured this struck a balance.
This example creates a dictionary, but of course the data type of d is not the key thing here.
If you're looking for something a bit more concise (but harder to understand):
text = 'Text1:/nText/nText2:/nText/nText/nText3:/nText'

parts = text.split('/n')
inds = [i for i, s in enumerate(parts) if s.endswith(':')] + [len(parts)]

result = {parts[i][:-1]: ' '.join(parts[i+1:j] for i, j in zip(inds, inds[1:])}
print(result)

This splits the text into parts like the first example, but then finds the indices of all the parts that end in ':' and constructs the dictionary by taking each element at such an index (except for the colon) as a key and everything up to the next index joined into a value. The zip() pairs each index with the next and the last with the length of parts, which is why it was added to the list of indices.

it's late, but I wanted to say thank you

You're welcome - I hope it helped. Maybe help someone else sometime.

Something like this perhaps...
keys = []
values = []
for item in text.split("\n"):
    if item.endswith(':'):
        keys.append(item[:-1])
        values.append([])
    else:
        values[-1].append(item)
d = dict(zip(keys, values))
print(d)

Output
{'Text1': ['Text'], 'Text2': ['Text', 'Text'], 'Text3': ['Text']}

If you don't like the lists of strings in the output, you can replace the last line with:
d = {key: ' '.join(values) for key, values in zip(keys, values)}

Output
{'Text1': 'Text', 'Text2': 'Text Text', 'Text3': 'Text'}

